# I cannot update a table field, error 3027(cannot update. Database object is read-only) keeps popping up

Tags: vba, ms-access

The email is able to be sent out but I keep receiving this error. This wasn't a problem before, the code worked fine and I was able to update a table field DateEmailSent but now that field can't be updated. This only happened after I created another form, could it be that the code in that form affected the code here.

```
Option Compare Database

Function GenerateEmail(MySQL As String)
On Error GoTo Exit_Function:
Dim oOutLook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As Mailitem
Dim currentDate As Date

currentDate = Date

Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(MySQL)
'MsgBox rs.RecordCount
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
   ' MsgBox rs!Email
    Do Until rs.EOF
    If IsNull(rs!Email) Then
        rs.MoveNext
    Else
        If oOutLook Is Nothing Then
         Set oOutLook = New Outlook.Application
        End If
        Set oEmailItem = oOutLook.CreateItem(olMailitem)
        With oEmailItem
                    .To = rs!Email
                    .CC = "josleasecollection@jos.com.sg"
                    .Subject = "End of Lease Product Collection Notification - " & rs!IDATender & " " & rs!PONumber & " CUSTOMER NAME: " & rs!AgencyName
                    .Body = "Dear Customer, " & vbCr & vbCr & _
                            "Notification of End of Lease Collection" & vbCr & _
                            "This is to inform you that leasing product(s) for PO #" & rs!PONumber & " will be expiring on " & rs!DueDate & vbCr & vbCr & _
                            "For a smooth and seamless collection process, you are required to: " & vbCr & _
                            "  - To appoint a single contact point (Name, email and mobile contacts) for coordination purposes." & vbCr & _
                            "  - To make verifications on the lease items for collection" & vbCr & _
                            "  - To consolidate lease equipment & allocate holding are for onsite work purposes." & vbCr & _
                            "  - To provide site clearance access if there are entry restrictions." & vbCr & _
                            "  - To remove any additional parts (i.e. RAM, Additional HD, Graphic cards) installed in the lease equipment that is not part of the lease contract and BIOS password lock." & vbCr & _
                            "  - To sign off all necessary asset & collection forms upon validations." & vbCr & vbCr & _
                            "Important Terms: " & vbCr & _
                            "  1.  Lease equipment must be return in full and good working condition (with the exception of fair wear & tear)." & vbCr & _
                            "      For Desktop, items to be collected with main unit as follows:" & vbCr & _
                            "      - Power Adapter/Cable, Keyboard, Mouse" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                            "      For Notebook, items to be collected with main unit as follows:" & vbCr & _
                            "      - Power Adapter, Carrying case, Mouse" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                            "      For Monitor, items to be collected with main unit as follows:" & vbCr & _
                            "      - VGA Cable" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                            "  2. Any loss of lease equipment, you are required to immediately inform JOS and we will advise the relevant procedures." & vbCr & _
                            "  3. Collection must be completed no later than 14 days after the expiry of lease. We reserve the right to impose a late return fees (calculated on a daily basis) for any lease equipment." & vbCr & _
                            "  4. JOS will send in onsite engineers for asset verification and assist you. If onsite engineers are not available, JOS will provide a handbook for hard disk removal before collection, to which you shall immediately conduct the hard disk removal at your end." & vbCr & _
                            "  5. JOS shall not be held liable for any non-removal of any additional parts." & vbCr & _
                            "  6. JOS shall be indemnified in the event that collection is unsuccessful by the termination date due to the default or unreasonable delay caused by the customer. " & vbCr & _
                            " Appreciate for your acknowledgement by replying to josleasecollection@jos.com.sg by " & currentDate

                    .Send
                    rs.Edit
                    rs!dateemailsent = Date
                    rs.Update
        End With
        Set oEmailItem = Nothing
        Set oOutLook = Nothing
        rs.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
Else

End If
```

This is the code for the new form i created.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub btnUpdateEmail_Click()
On Error GoTo Exit_UpdateEmail
Email_Update:
     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Dim qdf As QueryDef
     Dim sql As String

     Set db = CurrentDb()
     Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryUpdateEmail")

     sqlString = "UPDATE Company SET Company.Email = '" & Me.txtNewEmail & "' WHERE Company.ContractNumber = '" & Me.txtContractNumber & "' "
     qdf.sql = sqlString

      If Nz(Me.txtContractNumber, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a contract number"
        Resume Exit_Update
      ElseIf Nz(Me.txtNewEmail, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a new email address"
        Resume Exit_Update
      End If

      DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryUpdateEmail"

Exit_Update:
Exit Sub

Exit_UpdateEmail:
If Err.Number = 2501 Then
    Resume Exit_Update
Else
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Update
End If
End Sub
    rs.Close
    Exit_Function:
        Exit Function
    End Function
```

Comment: the problem is in the line ,  
rs!dateemailsent = Date , Probably you are having problems with the Date value , just inspect and see the DATE value in this line , error 3027 is caused bcoz tha table doesnt accept the value inserted , can you see what is the value of date ? and debug.print the MySQl ? plz !

Comment: Edit question to show the exact wording of the error message. Your conclusion about the new form possibly interfering is reasonable. How is that form associated with this process? Again, edit question to provide code and info.

Comment: @RonanVico The value of the date is Date/Time

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: @June7 the new form is supposed to update the email address of the customer in the same table as the field DateEmailSent

Comment: Why do you need code to edit/save data? Open bound form filtered to specific record, user inputs email into textbox bound to field, close form and that updates record. However, if this edit is attempted after opening recordset in the other form, that could be what is causing conflict. I don't recall ever having to program something like this and never encountered the error.

Comment: @June7 so I should remove the edit code?

Comment: That action is implied by my comment.

Comment: @June7 I tried that already, doesn't work

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Is the form bound to table and textbox bound to field?

Comment: Doesn't work means that I still have the same error message. The form isn't bound to the same table as the DateEmailSent field. The same for the textbox